# "channel [{channel-name}]: MSP error: channel doesn't exist" warning fails the instantiation of chaincode on Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to run the Hyperledger Fabric network, which consists of a single orderer, a single peer, and a cli. To learn the procedure of launching Hyperledger Fabric network, from creating crypto-related artifacts to running cli as a docker container, I execute them one by one.

Everything is okay, but when I try to instantiate the installed chaincode, the peer produces `channel [reputationch]: MSP error: channel doesn't exist` (`reputationch` is my channel name) and the instantiation has been failed.

(Check the below screenshot)
[image]

I'm not sure that this warning on the peer node causes the failure of the instantiation of chaincode, but I guess it is the reason.

My `crypto-config.yaml` and `configtx.yaml` are like below. They are nothing special because I just modified some names based on the official example.

[`crytp-config.yaml` and `configtx.yaml`](https://gist.github.com/byron1st/1755f38698338256ff5465ef13c2ed51)

And the script to create crypto-related artifacts based on the above yaml files is:

[script to create crypto-related artifacts](https://gist.github.com/byron1st/54f07e0d5afd4f4080286b874660ef30)

My running scripts to launch an orderer, a peer, and a cli are like below. It calls docker commands.

[running scripts to launch an orderer, a peer, and a cli](https://gist.github.com/byron1st/179a4f5920f9ae28291d698fc0e58c04)

After I launch a cli, I connect the cli using `docker exec -it cli bash`. Then, I run three commands, which work well without an error or a warning:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.operator.com:7050 -c reputationch -f ./channel-artifacts/reputation-channel.tx
peer channel update -o orderer.operator.com:7050 -c reputationch -f ./channel-artifacts/Company1anchors.tx
peer chaincode install -n mycc -v 1.0 -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/
```

Then, the following command is failed.

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.operator.com:7050 -C reputationch -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "OR ('Company1MSP.peer')"
```

My version information is:

- macOS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
- Go: 1.10
- Docker: Version 18.03.0-ce-mac59 (23608)
- Hyperledger Fabric: 1.1

  - `cryptogen`: 1.1.0
  - `configtxgen`: 1.1.0

Any kind of comment or help will be very great for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you also need your peers to join your channels. Which it seems like you are not doing here. If your peers do not join any channel, you will be getting this error. Make sure that your peers join channel before installing chaincode.
`peer channel join -b $CHANNEL_NAME.block`